# Is there a way to read an array in csv format?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

This code is what I'm used it.

```
dataset = np.loadtxt('path to dataset', delimeter=',')

x_train=dataset[:700,0:3]
y_train=dataset[:700,3]
x_test=dataset[700:,0:3]
y_test=dataset[700:,3]
```

And I have billions of learning data.

Putting this data in a csv file is a pain to the computer.

I use 'sleep' to fetch 100,000 data at a time into a numpy array.

Is there a way to read the data in memory directly in csv format?

Comment: python `readlines` loads the csv text into memory.

Comment: In the normal sense of the phrase, your use of `loadtxt` is reading an array in csv format.   That is, if the `loadtxt` works, then `dataset` is an array.  I'd suggest you talk with a friend who has a better grasp of English, and then rewrite the question.